# Fit width into A4 page using CSS print media query

Tags: html, css

I need to fit the content into a A4 page using landscape format, now the information does not fit in width so some information is just not printed and stays out of the paper area.

I try:

```
@page {
        margin: 0.1cm;
        size: landscape;
        orientation: landscape;
        size: A4;
        width: 99%;
        height: 99%;
    }
```

But still have information that stays out of the A4 page.

Comment: does the *information* have paddings/margins? the code you provided is not sufficient..

Comment: I just add padding: 0,1cm, it does not fit yet, there any property that can force to fit into A4 landscape format? I see information too long that pushes the information from the right, to out of the paper margins.